# Sonar how to run unit test successfully

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, automated-tests, sonarqube

I have a project built with maven and I recently integrated Sonar... It is really easy to configure Sonar to analyze you're project but I couldn't configure it to run my project unit test also. I tried something with Jacoco but I get some Seam error and all the other tests are skipped. By the way I'm using TestNG to run tests manually.

Comment: Can you post your step by step actions to analyze the project? You may be missing some step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar cannot run tests, it can only analyze testing reports.

You can run yourself JUnit ( using Maven or Ant for exemple ) and push reports to Sonar (try Sonar's Maven [plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/) for that)

or you can give yourself a build factory (try [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for exemple) and plug it to [sonar](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin).

Comment: Well then I want to reuse TestNG results. Isn't a way to show sonar the path to these results (xml file)?

Comment: This is not true, Sonar can run tests. If you look at the documentation http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven you will see they recommend turning off tests in the Maven build to avoid them being run twice, once when you build, once when you use Sonar.

Comment: both analyses you're talking about are run with maven :
first one during maven install goal, 
second one during maven sonar goal

Comment: @MarkButler your link is dead. Also, according to this https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/  sonar dropped the unit test execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the relevant [Analysis Parameters](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-UnitandIntegrationTests) of sonar to reuse the test reports from your earlier run.  You would set `sonar.dynamicAnalysis` property to `reuseReports` and specify the location of the reports in `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` or `sonar.surefire.reportPath` based on how you run the tests.

By the way, `mvn sonar:sonar` invokes maven's `test` goal, which runs unit tests as part of the analysis.  So ideally if your maven can run unit tests, sonar should be able to run them.